# Installing eccodes with conda install windows

Tags: python, anaconda, grib

I am trying to install eccodes using conda forge, following the advice on https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/eccodes, on a windows 10 computer.

I keep getting an error message:

`failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`
`failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`

Has anyone had difficulties with this before?

Edit: I found a work around by reinstalling conda-forge, and making a new virtual environment

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge eccodes That work at my Windows 10 PC without problems in a test environment. What is your exact output?

Comment: Exactly what conda command did you run ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think it may be to do with the version of conda I am using. Could you please let me know which version you are running?

Comment: 1.9.7 ... I don't think that is the reason. Maybe there are conflicts with other installed packages. The whole error message would be interessting.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't grab the entire error. I used this form to help as I assumed the issue was with conda-forge: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8051. I have over come the issue by using a new environment and reinstalling conda-forge

Comment: ok, good to hear that.